# Windows 10 which versions still get security updates?

Tags: windows-10

I'm a bit confused about the windows 10 versions and which versions still gets security updates.

In our company I regularly stumble upon notebooks with Windows 10 1703, 1709, 1909 and so on.
According to `winver`, these are all Windows 10 Pro.

On the Microsoft homepage, I've found this list:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/

From my understanding everything up to 1809 is not supported anymore and should be updated, but our IT-department says that these versions are still fine.

What information is correct? Should these systems be updated or do all versions still get security updates? Or is there some leeway with updating?

Comment: I would believe Microsoft before I would your IT dept.

Comment: Are they volume licensed?  It's not clear (to me) if volume licensed Pro would come under the Enterprise column. I guess not but perhaps.

Comment: @JohnDoe2991... Your IT team should explore pushing out Windows 10 feature updates. They probably struggle with that and standardizing the process so this is why there's a mix of the versions. Not sure how big the company is or how many machines total, but I've successfully updated a little under 2000 Windows 10 Enterprise OSes using WSUS and timing things out and a little PowerShell remote commands. In groups of course and not all at once. Sometimes there were problems I had to fix but overall it went well. Once you get past version1903, feature updates get better by the way in my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my understanding everything up to 1809 is not supported anymore and should be updated, but our IT-department says that these versions are still fine.

Microsoft supports Windows 10 Professional versions for 18 months.  Windows 10 Enterprise, Education, and Windows Server have a different lifecycle.  There are also versions of Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC and Windows Server that are supported for 10 years.  **Microsoft has documented the lifecycle on all their products.**

> What information is correct?

In this case, it would be your IT department, since they are the final authority on what versions of Windows will be allowed to exist on the network. As an Administrator of a network, if I found any user on my network attempting to install a newer version of Windows, that would result in their immediate dismissal from the company.

> Should these systems be updated or do all versions still get security updates?

The systems should only be updated on a schedule determined by your IT department.  Microsoft has support contracts for volume licenses that extend the support of specific versions and editions of Windows.

> is there some leeway with updating?

**You should allow your IT department determine what updates will be installed on their system.**  If they feel it's acceptable to run Windows 10 version 1703 then that is their decision.

Source: [Windows 10 Home and Pro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro)